# MIT reality mining

Tags: crowdsourcing

I'm going to work in Mobile Crowd sensing in my master of thesis . I need MIT reality mining  data so I had submitted in this site http://realitycommons.media.mit.edu/realitymining.html
and it had told me the download linke will be sent for me in next few day. but they dont send me yet .
 can someone help , or tell me why?

Comment: This is likely a bit of a stretch on topic -- there's any number of reasons ... e-mail isn't instantaneous (not 15 years ago, you'd sometimes see up to 2 day delays).  Today with spam filters, it's possible they replied back, but something on your side ate the response.  And then it's possible that the website CGI isn't working ... or the person it e-mails it on vacation (or no longer works there, and they never fixed it).  As there's a 'contact us' page on that site, try the email addresses listed there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its more or less MIT's problem/policy, not open data se's

Comment: Did you answer "no" to the two questions in the form?

Comment: I filled the form, never got any answer either.